# HTML Tables vs Lists for form inputs

Tags: html, forms, html-table, html-lists

Everyone knows that you should be only using tables for semantic purposes, to markup tabular data.

I personally use ordered lists to markup form inputs.

However I have seen arguments pro using tables to markup forms, the argument being that you are inputting tabular data.

I think this is only true in very specific circumstances, where the data inputted would be naturally outputt/represented as a table. However I'm guessing this has a downside that it makes the (very useful) label tag redundant, as the table th tags should (in theory) represent the column titles.

I suppose what I'm trying to say is that I think tabular forms have their downsides, but I'd be interested in knowing what the community thinks of the pro's and cons of using lists vs tables for inputs.

The reason I bring this up, is that the w3 specs do not offer guidance (from what I can find) on marking up forms. As far as I can tell, lists should be used mostly unless the inputted data really fits tabular data (e.g. your inputting into a Google spreadsheet).

This has the danger of turning into a battleground, so please consider before posting and perhaps it may make a good wiki page demonstrating where best to use each.

-thanks
Alex.

Comment: Why use either? Aren't forms, fieldsets, labels, inputs, textareas and selects enough semantics for anyone?

Comment: No, they're not. They're semantic, but don't give you much layout control. You need wrapping HTML for that, usually lists or tables.

Comment: @Diodeus - If you want layout, use css.

Comment: CSS alone cannot format complex forms.

Comment: Hi, interesting comments thanks. I must admit, I find that only using forms esc inputs too limiting for layouts. Instead additional markup is needed. Be it div'/span's or preferably li's. I find ol's li's give a smidgen more "meaning" over div's, as they depict the order a form needs to be filled in. An example li implemention could be http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms but perhaps this isn't needed as much any more, as perhaps input layouts can be tamed in A grade browsers (rhetorical question - perhaps something for another day :-) )

Comment: @Alex - IMHO, the order that forms need to be filled in, can and should be determined by the tab order, because that's the order that non-sighted and keyboard restricted users will experience the form controls in. Not only is there's no need for an ordered list, but it only has the potential to confuse by conflicting with the tab order. FWIW, if you need additional mark-up to hang CSS off, I recommend that you use semantics free elements like div and span, that way you won't cause semantic confusion.

Comment: @Alohci very interesting. I did think of tab order via input elements. But i've never thought of it conflicting with the list elements.. good point. And instead the using tags to purposefully be non-semantic tags... very interesting point, an eye opener for me. +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My rule**: if it has grid-like properties and the rows and columns contain **logically associated** data, then it's a table.

Comment: I like that, nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

use form controls and form elements for forms.
don't use either tables or lists. if your form is that you complex you can nest fieldsets and even forms in html5.

examples

http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-a-cool-and-usable-css3-search-box   http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/form/demo/index.html  off top of my head. those don't even implement the minimum controls/elements though. need fieldset, label, and legend

Comment: Interesting albert, thanks for your response. Do you have examples that I can take a look at of forms that do not use additional markup? I've always had trouble in only using form controls, so I'd be interested in seeing any cool techniques.

Comment: thanks for the examples, very clean markup +1 from me. I think they'll work very nicely when you can guarantee the html outputted i.e. css purposefully made for a number of given forms, but I suppose may cause problems with general purpose CSS for many forms across a large ... but that's for another day :-)